# Ignore using directive for certain projects if the library doesn't exist

Tags: c#, dll

I am working on various projects and I need some help but not if this is possible.

What I have are various C# projects which I want to have a C# Library that all my projects can 
use, lets call this `library 1`.

Library 1 can make use of another library. lets call this `library 2`.

All projects will always use library 1 but not all projects will use library 2 within library 1.

Therefore at the moment if I create a new C# project and include library 1, I then get an error saying that library 2 isn't available. I don't really want to import library 2 unless the main project actually requires it. Therefore is there a way to make it so library 1 can ignore the using directive if library 2 is not available.

Hope this make sense, thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you use "#ifdef", and then define/undefine the conditional variable in your project settings?

Comment: How do you define project settings, usually just keep them at the default at how VS2010 makes them

Comment: Add a line on the top of the code `#define INCLUDE_DLL` for example, Or `#undef INCLUDE_DLL` for a compile variable named `INCLUDE_DLL`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, never thought of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do what you're asking to do. If not all projects will need library 2, then you have two ways you *should* solve it:

> Option 1: Refactor your projects so that library 2 is only included
> when needed. If the executable project is the one that decides if
> library 2 is necessary, then that's the project that should reference
> it (or not).
>
> Option 2: Just include library 2 all of the time. If the main executable doesn't
> need it, so be it. But since library 1 references it, you'll need it.

I would suggest option 1. Just by asking this question, I think you have a dependency issue, and that's what should be fixed. There might be some complex solution for hacking around this, but that's not good for long-term maintainability.

I would also suggest googling [Stable Dependencies Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/stability.pdf).